# GMAP.Net Google Satellite map error in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps, gmap.net

Tried to use GMAP.NET in winform using C#, when I set map properties to **GoogleSatelliteMapProvider** it gives an error. **Exception :The remote Server returned in error:(404) Not found**.

I am using latest GMAP.Net version. 1.7.0.0 

Below please find the code.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gmap.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.GoogleSatelliteMapProvider.Instance;
        GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerAndCache;
        gmap.SetPositionByKeywords("Country_Name");
        gmap.Position = new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(22.63, 71.58);
        gmap.Zoom = 5;
        gmap.MaxZoom = 18;
        gmap.MinZoom = 2;
        gmap.Bearing = 0;
        gmap.CanDragMap = true;         
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this map provider seems to be not working, you might want to address this at the [issues page](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic) of the project.

Comment: Sure I will ... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should download the lastest version of GMap.Net, it's 1.7.5. I had the same problem than you and i fixed it with that. To install GMap.NET - Great Maps for Windows Presentation, run the following command in the Package Manager Console:

PM> Install-Package GMap.NET.Presentation